# Deck.GL ScatterplotLayer does not render points

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I've been scratching my head over this one for way too long. I've got the simplest React App, which passes some data as a prop to WhateverMap (so-called because I've been trying out many different Map libraries).

However, when I try to plot the data points on Deck.GL using a ScatterplotLayer, I simply do not see them on the rendered map.

According to React Developer Tools, the ScatterplotLayer component did receive my datapoints.

I'm expecting to see some markers along a specific part of the train tracks in Berlin.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import WhateverMap from './Map';
import Table from './Table';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // Trip along the Ringbahn
    data: [
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-10000, 'coordinates': [52.536131,13.447444], 'temperature': 19},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-9000, 'coordinates': [52.538221,13.44376], 'temperature': 20},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-8000, 'coordinates': [52.540247,13.43899], 'temperature': 21},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-7000, 'coordinates': [52.541751,13.43513], 'temperature': 22},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-6000, 'coordinates': [52.54264,13.433692], 'temperature': 23},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-5000, 'coordinates': [52.543007,13.431339], 'temperature': 24},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-4000, 'coordinates': [52.543755,13.428731], 'temperature': 25},
        {'timestamp': Date.now()-3000, 'coordinates': [52.544295,13.427207], 'temperature': 27}
    ]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <WhateverMap data={this.state.data} />
        <Table data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

WhateverMap:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl';
import DeckGL, { ScatterplotLayer } from 'deck.gl';

const mapbox_token = ''
const mapConfig = {
  center: [52.540875, 13.438545],
  zoom: 13
};

class WhateverMap extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      viewport: {
        width: 960,
        height: 600,
        latitude: mapConfig.center[0],
        longitude: mapConfig.center[1],
        zoom: mapConfig.zoom,
        startDragLngLat: mapConfig.center,
      },
    };

    this.onChangeViewport = this.onChangeViewport.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeViewport(viewport) {
    this.setState({
      viewport: { ...this.state.viewport, ...viewport }
    });
  }

  initialize(gl) {
    gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
    gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
  }

  render() {
    const { viewport } = this.state;
    const { data } = this.props;

    const plot_position_layer = new ScatterplotLayer({
        id: 'scatterplot-layer',
        data,
        pickable: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
        radiusScale: 6,
        radiusMinPixels: 1,
        radiusMaxPixels: 100,
        getPosition: d => d.coordinates,
    })

    return (
      <div className="reactmapgldeckgl">
        <MapGL
          {...viewport}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={mapbox_token}
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
          onChangeViewport={this.onChangeViewport}
        >
          <DeckGL
            {...viewport}
            onWebGLInitialized={this.initialize}
            layers={[plot_position_layer]}
          />
        </MapGL>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WhateverMap;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the answer. You code seems to be right, however, some tweaking seems to resolve the error.

```
const plot_position_layer = new ScatterplotLayer({
  id: 'scatterplot-layer',
  data,
  pickable: true,
  opacity: 0.8,
  radiusScale: 30,  // make the dots visible or darker background
  radiusMinPixels: 15, // make the dots visible or darker background
  radiusMaxPixels: 100,

  getPosition: d => [d.coordinates[1], d.coordinates[0]], // -> Essential Change here

  getColor: d => [255, 255, 255], // make the dots visible or darker background
})
```

> Now, what has changed essentially is `getPosition: d => [d.coordinates[1], d.coordinates[0]]`

Strangely, the getPosition function is expected to return an array with the first element as longitude instead of latitude which is why the points were out of bounds.

[image]

Have a look at their example [here](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/examples/website/scatterplot/app.js) at line number 11.

```
// Source data CSV
const DATA_URL =
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber-common/deck.gl-data/master/examples/scatterplot/manhattan.json'; // eslint-disable-line

export const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: -74, //remember, longitude starts with 74
  latitude: 40.7,
  zoom: 11,
  maxZoom: 16,
  pitch: 0,
  bearing: 0
};
```

and the `DATA_URL` reads as

```
[
  [-73.986022,40.730743,2], // the first element is longitude
  [-73.984293,40.729468,1],
  [-73.987752,40.732017,1],
  [-73.986887,40.730105,2],
  ...
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Amazing! How much time did you need to find out this little detail? How can I get equally good at troubleshooting such things? Is it just experience?
Usually when faced with a problem like this I always end up spending a few hours on it and then at the end of the day I'm tired and unproductive

Comment: Thanks @randomshinichi! It didn't take much time. My suggestion is run the example. If it works there, try replacing it with your own props (but step by step) and see where it breaks! I guess it is with experience as I have been there struggling a million times  